# how can I slice an element with mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

How can I slice elements with  ***mootools***?
for example I want to inject "`</ul><ul>`" (not`<ul></ul>`) before all "li" that have a "span" child.
source code:

```
<ul>

   <li>
       <a></a>
   </li>

   <li>
       <a></a>
   </li>
<!-- i want insert "</ul><ul>" Here -->
   <li> 
       <span></span>
   </li>

   <li>
      <a></a>
   </li>

   <li>
     <a></a>
   </li>

   <li>
     <a></a>
   </li>

<!-- i want insert "</ul><ul>" Here--> 
   <li>
      <span></span>
   </li>

   <li>
      <a></a>
   </li>

   <li>
      <a></a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

output :

```
<ul>

       <li>
           <a></a>
       </li>

       <li>
           <a></a>
       </li>
</ul>

<ul>
       <li> 
           <span></span>
       </li>

       <li>
          <a></a>
       </li>

       <li>
         <a></a>
       </li>

       <li>
         <a></a>
       </li>

</ul>

<ul>
       <li>
          <span></span>
       </li>

       <li>
          <a></a>
       </li>

       <li>
          <a></a>
       </li>

    </ul>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `div`s are ***not*** valid children of `ul` or `ol`; the ***only*** valid child of these elements is `li`. If you insert `div` elements into the `ul` then you will have invalid mark-up.

Comment: ok.tnx.how can i insert </ul><ul> Instead of </div><div>

Comment: I honestly don't know [tag:mootools], so I'm not in a good position to help you. I'll try and work something out with plain JavaScript, though. Can you edit your question to show the output you expect? Or at least show what elements you want to wrap together?

Comment: Can you tell use why you are trying to do this, I get the feeling there is an alternate way to achieve what you want. For example if the original HTML is generated. You might just want to regenerate it. If it's generated from an array, you might want multiple arrays to denote the different <ul>'s.

Comment: because I create joomla framework and need a little change to joomla output .I have 3 way:hack joomla core or create new module or use javascript.
i don't want create extra module and plugin or hack joomla for some reason. so Third way is best way for me . Apart from this mootools can Simply insert regular html tag but how posible to add unusual code or part of code whit mootools (like:</div><div>). I think it is useful in many places.  is it possible?

Comment: you cannot just output random closing tags where you want unless you parse the innerHTML as text and then output it - though this will destroy all inner els and recreate them, removing any events you may have attached. the sensible solution is to loop through all child lis, find if there's a span, move all lis thus far into a new ul and continue, at the end of which you can output the new uls instead of the old one - but keeping the inner els intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be a possible implementation of a slice function for the mootools Element class:

```
Element.implement({
    'slice' : function(keys) {
        var keys = Array.from(keys),
            newParent = false;
        this.getChildren().each(function(child) {
            if(keys.contains(child)) {
                newParent = new Element(this.get("tag"))
                    .inject(newParent?newParent:this, "after");
            }
            if(newParent) 
                newParent.adopt(child);

        }, this);
    }
});
window.addEvent("domready", function() {
    $("toSlice").slice($$(".keyElt"));
});
```

and its jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/cFukg/1/